# How do you share devices in Artik Cloud

Tags: iot

How do you share devices with someone else on ARTIK Cloud. I am trying to do this through using the APIs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our device sharing documentation. https://developer.artik.cloud/documentation/advanced-features/device-sharing.html
This also can be done using your my.artik.cloud account. 
You will need to:
 Create a device share:
   POST /devices//shares
In which you share the device with a someone.  - first you must obtain the device id and provide an email of the person you want to share the device with.

More details in our API reference documentation:
https://developer.artik.cloud/documentation/api-reference/rest-api.html#create-a-device-share.